# Using .then with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call:

```
p.data = function(){

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/data',
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('done');
        //do something with data here
        p.dummyDataVar = data[0];
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('fail');
    }).
    always(function(){
        console.log('always');
    });

};
```

This is called by:

```
this.data()
    .then(p.mySecondFunction);
```

I wish to call the data, then on done assign some vars with that data, then once this is all done I want to do mySecondFunction. But in the above code the second function is happening before the ajax call.

Also, I would like mySecondFunction to be called not matter whether the ajax call fails or not.

Comment: Can't see an error on your code. When you say it is happening before, how do know it?

Comment: did you try `$.ajax().then` ?

Comment: `p.data().always(fn)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.always()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) for this. It's already in you code.

> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.

```
p.data = function () {

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/data',
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('done');
        //do something with data here
        p.dummyDataVar = data[0];
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('fail');
    }).always(function () {
        //Call whatever you want
    });

};
```

Comment: Thanks, can I return the ajax call, without a .always() and declare the .always on the method. this.data().always(). Even if in the data method .done is declared on the ajax call itself.

Comment: I think you're trying to do something like this? http://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1022/jquery-ajax-deferred-promises